# convert from char to hex in C++

Tags: visual-c++, types

I'm doing a C++ program with a function that only accept input data in the format

```
\x1A\x2B\x3C\x4D\x5E\x6F
```

but the output of the previous function is a string of characters:

```
1A2B3C4D5E6F
```

How can I change the character string `1A2B3C4D5E6F` to `\x1A\x2B\x3C\x4D\x5E\x6F` so that I can use it as the input for another function?

Comment: You can do it by writing some code - what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sprintf` for getting strings in the format that you want. You can read-up on this function [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/).

Comment: imho that's more C then C++... using streams in C++ would be better suited I guess

Comment: @Tony The Tiger: Yes, but IMHO, it is also a very simple way of getting it done. There are a number of ways of other doing this. For example, one could use `sstream` or `boost::format` to achieve this.